# Heat equation with zero boundary conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, heat-equation

I am asked to solve the following problem 
$$\begin{cases}
u_t-u_{xx} = u + \sin 2x \,& 0 < x < \pi, t >0\\
u(x,0)=0 &  0 \leq x \leq \pi\\
u(0,t)=u(\pi, t) = 0 & t >0
\end{cases}$$

So I first did seek for a solution of the form $v(x,t) = e^{-t}u(x,t)$ to "kill" that $u$ term. Transforming the problem we get 
$$\begin{cases}
v_t - v_{xx} = e^{-t}\sin 2x \, & 0<x<\pi t>0\\
v(x,0) = 0 & 0 \leq x \leq \pi\\
v(0,t)=v(\pi,t)=0 & t>0
\end{cases}$$

Now i'd try to solve the homogeneous problem (without the $e^{-t}\sin 2x $ term), and apply the variation of parameters method, that is seeking for solutions of the form $v(x,t) = X(x)T(t)$.

The $T' = \lambda T$ equation has a general solution of the form $T(t) = C e^{\lambda t}$, and for the other equation, considering the case $\lambda < 0$ since the other cases yield trivial solutions, letting $\lambda = - \mu^2$
$$X(x) = A \cos (\mu x) + B \sin (\mu x)$$
and applying the boundary conditions, $0 = X(0) = A$ so $A = 0$ and $0 = X(\pi) = B \sin (\mu \pi)$ so $ \mu = n$ for $n$ and integer. Therefore
$$v(x,t) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} C_n e^{-n^2 t} \sin (nx)$$

But now, applying the other boundary condition, we get 
$$0 = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} C_n \sin (nx)$$
so all $C_n = 0$ and the solutions is again the trivial one. The question then is

> Where did I commit a mistake? Is this possible?

Comment: With these initial conditions, the only solution to the homogeneous problem is the trivial one.  So what you have is correct.

Comment: @Paul Thanks, so how should I work then to find a solution for the original problem?

Comment: @user313212 If you have a homogeneous solution, find your particular solution, and you know that $v(x,t)$ is the super position of them both, then just transform back.

Comment: I would try a Fourier transform of the equation in the spatial domain, or a Laplace Transform in the time domain.

Comment: Finding the solution to the homogeneous problem is not necessarily needed, you can use it to find an eigenfunction expansion for the original problem. This would give you the solution you seek.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following my hint, you should be able to see that the second coefficient($C_2$) of the eigenfunction expansion should be nonzero. Thus arriving to the solution

$$v(x,t) = -\frac{1}{3}\left(e^{-t} - e^{-4t}\right)\sin{(2x)}$$

Hence,

$$u(x,t) = -\frac{1}{3}\left(e^{-2t} - e^{-5t}\right)\sin{(2x)}$$

is the unique solution to the original problem.

Comment: In particular, you got that the homogeneous solution correctly, but now you should plug the homogeneous solution back into your problem to solve for the coefficients.